# Python-docx delete table code not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, python-docx

I am trying to do the following tasks:

- Open a DOCX file using `python-docx` library
- Count the # of tables in the DOCX: `table_count = len(document.tables)`
- The function `read_docx_table()` extracts the table, creates a dataframe.

My objective here is as following:

- Extract ALL tables from the DOCX
- Find the table that is empty
- Delete the empty table
- Save the DOCX

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
import numpy as np

document = Document('tmp.docx')
table_count = len(document.tables)
table_num= table_count
print(f"Number of tables in the Document is: {table_count}")
nheader=1
i=0

def read_docx_table(document, table_num=1, nheader=1):
    table = document.tables[table_num-1]
    data = [[cell.text for cell in row.cells] for row in table.rows]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    if nheader ==1:
        df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True)
    elif nheader == 2:
        outside_col, inside_col = df.iloc[0], df.iloc[1]
        h_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(outside_col, inside_col)))
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=h_index).drop(df.index[[0,1]]).reset_index(drop=True)
    elif nheader > 2:
        print("More than two headers. Not Supported in Current version.")
        df = pd.DataFrame()
    return df

def Delete_table(table):
    print(f" We are deleting table now. Table index is {table}")
    print(f"Type of index before casting is {type(table)}")
    index = int(table)
    print(f"Type of index is {type(index)}")
    try:
        print("Deleting started...")
        document.tables[index]._element.getparent().remove(document.tables[index]._element)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

while (i < table_count):
    print(f"Dataframe table number is {i} ")
    df = read_docx_table(document,i,nheader)
    df = df.replace('', np.nan)
    print(df)
    if (df.dropna().empty):
        print(f'Empty DataFrame. Table Index = {i}')
        print('Deleting Empty table...')
        #Delete_table(i)
        try:
            document.tables[i]._element.getparent().remove(document.tables[i]._element)
            print("Table deleted...")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        
    else:
        print("DF is not empty...")
        print(df.size)
    
    i+=1
document.save('OUT.docx')
```

My INPUT docx has `3 tables`:

[image]

But, my CODE gives me the following **Output**:

[image]

It is keeping the empty table and deleting the non-empty table.

Is there something I am missing? I am doubting my logic to check the Table is empty using `if (df.dropna().empty):`

Answer (score 1):

The `df.dropna().empty` logic drops any tables that have no non-header rows lacking a blank cell. Is that the intent? If so, then it seems okay to me.

Two points:

- The `docx` library does not necessarily return the tables in the order they exist in the document.
- When you delete a table with your code, you immediately skip the next one to be returned (which might not be the next one in the document due to the above) because you increment your counter after deleting. That results in not processing all the tables.

As I worked through the logic, I did some rearrangements to understand it. I think you might also have been getting some exceptions being emitted on indexing into the tables after deleting? I included my edits below - hopefully they help.

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
import numpy as np

def read_docx_table(document, table_num, header_rows):
    table = document.tables[table_num]
    data = [[cell.text for cell in row.cells] for row in table.rows]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    if header_rows == 1:
        df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True)
    elif header_rows == 2:
        outside_col, inside_col = df.iloc[0], df.iloc[1]
        h_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(outside_col, inside_col)))
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=h_index).drop(df.index[[0,1]]).reset_index(drop=True)
    else: # header_rows not 1 or 2
        print("More than two headers. Not Supported in Current version.")
        df = pd.DataFrame()
    return df

def table_is_empty(document, table_num, header_rows):
    df = read_docx_table(document, table_num, header_rows)
    df = df.replace('', np.nan)
    return df.dropna().empty

def delete_table(document, table_num):
    document.tables[table_num]._element.getparent().remove(document.tables[table_num]._element)

document = Document('tmp.docx')

header_rows = 1

table_count = len(document.tables)

print(f"Number of tables in the input document is: {table_count}")

table_num = 0
while table_num < table_count:
    if table_is_empty(document, table_num, header_rows):
        delete_table(document, table_num)
        table_count = len(document.tables)
    else:
        table_num += 1

print(f"Number of tables in the output document is: {table_count}")

document.save('OUT.docx')
```